# Apollo GraphQL mutation: Variable is not defined by operation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql

I am able to get graphql to work without error in both the client and server graphql playground. However, when I try calling the mutation in the client file I end up with `Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400` and in the networks tab I am told `Variable \"$ParkingSpaces\" is not defined by operation \"saveParkingLot\"`. The mutation is suppose to accept an array of objects.

The typeDefs are:

```js
type ParkingSpace {
   id: Int!
   ownerID: String!
   parkingID: String!
  }

input ParkingSpaces {
   id: String!
   ownerID: String!
   parkingID: String!
  }

type Mutation {
    saveParkingLot(parkingLot: [ParkingSpaces]): [ParkingSpace]!
}
```

The resolver is deleting the existing information from database and then saving the new one

```js
saveParkingLot: async (_, args) => {
      ParkingSpace.collection.drop();
      const parkingArray = new ParkingSpace({
        parkingLot: args.parkingLot,
      });
      parkingArray.save();
      return args.parkingLot;
    },
  },
```

But the code fails on the client. I left out the `{}` in `variables:` because it creates a syntax error for some reason

```js
  const SAVE_PARKING_LOT = gql`
    mutation saveParkingLot($parkingLot: ParkingSpaces!) {
      saveParkingLot(parkingLot: $ParkingSpaces) {
        id
        ownerID
        parkingID
      }
    }
  `;

  const [saveParkingLot] = useMutation(SAVE_PARKING_LOT, {
    onError(err) {
      console.log(err);
    },
  });
  //Mutation fails when called
  const saveParkingLotButton = () => {
       saveParkingLot({
      variables: [
        { id: "0", ownerID: "0", parkingID: "0" },
        { id: "1", ownerID: "1", parkingID: "1" },
        { id: "2", ownerID: "2", parkingID: "2" },
        { id: "3", ownerID: "3", parkingID: "3" },
      ],
    }); 

  };
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your client query to this:

```
    mutation saveParkingLot($parkingLot: [ParkingSpaces]) {
      saveParkingLot(parkingLot: $parkingLot) {
        id
        ownerID
        parkingID
      }
    }
```

and in the variables section use like this:

```
    variables: {
       parkingLot: [
        { id: "0", ownerID: "0", parkingID: "0" },
        { id: "1", ownerID: "1", parkingID: "1" },
        { id: "2", ownerID: "2", parkingID: "2" },
        { id: "3", ownerID: "3", parkingID: "3" },
      ]
    },
```

Reference: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables